# how can i store datetime in the table without time fraction part?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm inserting sample call data to the table `ContactCallDetail`. when I query the data inserted I'm getting datetime in the format `yy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss-ff`

```
declare @StartDateTime datetime = convert(varchar, getdate(), 20);
declare @EndDateTime datetime = dateadd(ss,20,@StartDateTime);
INSERT INTO ContactCallDetail values(0,NULL,'+xxxxx545xx77',@StartDateTime,@EndDateTime,0);
GO

select * from ContactCallDetail 
SessionID   SessionSeqNum   originatorID    CallingDN   StartDateTime   EndDateTime Transfer
100000  0   NULL    +xxxxx5453xx7   2022-02-28 20:11:34.000 2022-02-28 20:11:54.000 0
```

I need to store the datetime without fractions part(ff). how can I achieve that? i want to see `2022-02-28 20:11:34` instead of `2022-02-28 20:11:34.000`

Comment: store the data without fractions.

Answer (score 6):

The `datetime` data type always stores fractional seconds with a 1/300 second precision. Use `datetime2(0)` if you don't need fractional seconds. This will also save storage space (2 bytes).

Comment: seems this is what i need but i now have a problem. if i try to use GetDate() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP i'm getting this error when inserting:
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: @MoeKronz, that error is unrelated to the data type. Make sure your INSERT statement column name list matches the number of values provided.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure and to add to @DanGuzman 's answer, you need to change the datatype of the StartDateTime and EndDateTime columns in the ContactCallDetail table to datetime2(0).

That will also make it so you don't have to do CONVERT either on the way in or the way out.